# Returning one list of results after calling a recursive function that forms strings

Tags: python, python-3.x

When calling a recursive function the forms strings- how can I return a list of strings instead of returning separate strings that belong to different calls ?

For example:

```
def printer_helper(str, pos, n, open, close):
  if (close == n):
    for i in str:
      print(i, end="")
    print()
    return
  else:
    if (open > close):
      str[pos] = '>'
      printer_helper(str, pos + 1, n, open, close + 1)
    if (open < n):
      str[pos] = '<'
      printer_helper(str, pos + 1, n, open + 1, close)


printer(['', '', '', '', '', ''],2)
```

The output is

<><>

<<>>

I **tried** initiating a list (lst =[]) before the first if and adding lst.append(i) instead of print (i) but I get None.
What I wish to get is:
[<><>, <<>>]

The source of the example : 
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-all-combinations-of-balanced-parentheses/

Comment: Why not *return* the strings rather than print them? Functions which work by side-effect rather than return value are usually not natural candidates for recursion. More generally -- functions which *print* a value rather than return it (unless they are top-level I/O functions) are almost always less useful than functions which return a value (which the caller can then print if they want).

Comment: `tried initiating a list (lst =[]) before the first if and adding lst.append(i) instead of print (i) but I get separate lists of single entry: [<><>]` - can you include that version in your question?

Comment: I now get only None a result and not what I got before. I'll try recovering the code and update the question accordingly. Thanks for your comment.